# Converting character to date in lubridate

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a character column of a df looking like:

```
a <- "6/10/21 19:34"
```

where the order is m/d/Y H:m.

I can't figure out why I am not able to convert it into datetime object.

I tried with:

```
mdy_hms(a,tz=Sys.timezone())
```

But I can't find a viable solution.

Comment: You need mdy_hm, there are no seconds in your input.

Comment: Either `mdy_hm(a,tz=Sys.timezone())` or `mdy_hms(paste0(a, ":00"),tz=Sys.timezone())`.